# Data replication or API Gateway Aggregation: which one to choose using microservices?

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, api-gateway, eventual-consistency

As an example, let's say that I'm building a simple social network. I currently have two services:

- `Identity`, managing the users, their personal data (e-mail, password hashes, etc.) and their public profiles (username) and authentication
- `Social`, managing the users' posts, their friends and their feed

The `Identity` service can give the public profile of an user using its API at `/api/users/{id}`:

```json
// GET /api/users/1 HTTP/1.1
// Host: my-identity-service

{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "cat_sun_dog"
}
```

The `Social` service can give a post with its API at `/api/posts/{id}`:

```json
// GET /api/posts/5 HTTP/1.1
// Host: my-social-service

{
  "id": 5,
  "content": "Cats are great, dogs are too. But, to be fair, the sun is much better.",
  "authorId": 1
}
```

That's great, but my client, a web app, would like to show the post with the **author's name**, and it would preferably receive the following JSON data in one single REST request.

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "content": "Cats are great, dogs are too. But, to be fair, the sun is much better.",
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "cat_sun_dog"
  }
}
```

I found two main ways to approach this.

## Data replication

As described in [Microsoft's guide for data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/distributed-data-management#challenge-3-how-to-achieve-consistency-across-multiple-microservices) and [Microsoft's guide for communication between microservices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture#asynchronous-microservice-integration-enforces-microservices-autonomy), it's possible for a microservice to replicate the data it needs by setting up an event bus (such as RabbitMQ) and consuming events from other services:

> And finally (and this is where most of the issues arise when building microservices), if your initial microservice needs data that's originally owned by other microservices, do not rely on making synchronous requests for that data. Instead, **replicate or propagate that data** (only the attributes you need) into the initial service's database by using eventual consistency (typically by using integration events, as explained in upcoming sections).

Therefore, the `Social` service can **consume events** produced by the `Identity` service such as `UserCreatedEvent` and `UserUpdatedEvent`.  Then, the `Social` service can have in its very own database **a copy of all the users, but only the required data** (their `Id` and `Username`, nothing more).

With this eventual consistent approach, the `Social` service now has all the required data for the UI, all in one request!

```json
// GET /api/posts/5 HTTP/1.1
// Host: my-social-service

{
  "id": 5,
  "content": "Cats are great, dogs are too. But, to be fair, the sun is much better.",
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "cat_sun_dog"
  }
}
```

**Benefits:**

- Makes the `Social` service totally independent from the `Identity` service; it can work totally fine without it
- Retrieving the data requires less network roundtrips
- Provides data for cross-service validation (e.g. check if the given user exists)

**Drawbacks and questions:**

- Takes some time for a change to propagate
- The system is absolutely RUINED for some users if some messages fail to get through due to [a disaster](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-france-ovh-fire-idUSKBN2B20NU) that fried all your replicated queues!
- What if, one day, I need more data from the user, like their `ProfilePicture`?
- What to do if I want to add a new service with the same replicated data?

## API Gateway aggregation

As described in [Microsoft's guide for data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/distributed-data-management#challenge-2-how-to-create-queries-that-retrieve-data-from-several-microservices), it's possible to create an API gateway that aggregates data from two requests: one to the `Social` service, and another to the `Identity` service.

Therefore, we can have an API gateway action (`/api/posts/{id}`) implemented as such, in pseudo-code for ASP.NET Core:

```cs
[HttpGet("/api/posts/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPost(int id) 
{
  var post = await _postService.GetPostById(id);
  if (post is null) 
  {
    return NotFound();
  }

  var author = await _userService.GetUserById(post.AuthorId);
  return Ok(new 
  {
    Id = post.Id,
    Content = post.Content,
    Author = new 
    {
      Id = author.Id,
      Username = author.Username
    }
  });
}
```

Then, a client just uses the API gateway and gets all the data in one query, without any client-side overhead:

```json
// GET /api/posts/5 HTTP/1.1
// Host: my-api-gateway

{
  "id": 5,
  "content": "Cats are great, dogs are too. But, to be fair, the sun is much better.",
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "cat_sun_dog"
  }
}
```

**Benefits:**

- Very easy to implement
- Always gives the up-to-date data
- Gives a centralized place to cache API queries

**Drawbacks and questions:**

- Increased latency: in this case, it's due to two sequential network roundtrips
- The action breaks if the `Identity` service is down, although this can be mitigated using the [circuit breaker pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern), the client won't see the author's name anyway
- Unused data might get still queried and waste resources (but that's marginal most of the time)

Having those two options: **aggregation on the API gateway** and **data replication on individual microservices using events**, **which one to use for which situation, and how to implement them correctly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I strongly favor state replication via events in durable log-structured storage over services making synchronous (in the logical sense, even if executed in a non-blocking fashion) queries.

Note that all systems are, at a sufficiently high level, eventually consistent: because we don't stop the world to allow an update to a service to happen, there's always a delay from update to visibility elsewhere (including in a user's mind).

In general, if you lose your datastores, things get ruined.  However, logs of immutable events give you active-passive replication for nearly free (you have a consumer of that log which replicates events to another datacenter): in a disaster you can make the passive side active.

If you need more events than you are already publishing, you just add a log.  You can seed the log with a backfilled dump of synthesized events from the state before the log existed (e.g. dump out all the current `ProfilePicture`s).

When you think of your event bus as a replicated log (e.g. by implementing it using Kafka), consumption of an event doesn't prevent arbitrarily many other consumers from coming along later (it's just incrementing your read-position in the log).  So that allows for other consumers to come along and consume the log for doing their own remix.  One of those consumers could be simply replicating the log to another datacenter (enabling that active-passive).

Note that once you allow services to maintain their own views of the important bits of data from other services, you are in practice doing Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS); it's thus a good idea to familiarize yourself with CQRS patterns.

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution, thanks! But what happens if a new update to my user service comes and the user has a new property: its `Biography`. This data wasn't present in the previous logs, which makes it tricky to manipulate. Also, when adding a new microservice, does it need to dump all of the users? If so, how long will that take (assuming there's around 200,000 users) and how to do it correctly?

Comment: And, what if, for some reason, the user service failed to send a message after a new user has been created because of a catastrophic crash that destroyed the [in-memory outbox](https://masstransit-project.com/articles/outbox.html#in-memory-outbox-take-out-the-trash)?

Comment: I don't know why SO didn't notify me on the `Biography` comment, only just seeing it now.

There's basically two choices for the consuming service: either they don't need to know about `Biography` so they can ignore the `Biography` part of the updates or they do need to know about `Biography`.  In the former case, you code the consumer so that it ignores things it doesn't need to care about.  In the latter case, it's best to update the consumer before updating the producer.

Comment: As for the catastrophic failure to deliver a message, the article outlines one approach (building a recovery process which will rebuild the message to be sent from what was written to the DB), but I personally prefer the event-sourcing approach for that, which is kind of the inverse: only update your local state after the message you put in the outbox has been sent (i.e. if the event wasn't published, the user wasn't actually created).

Comment: I see, thanks! By the way, considering my API has a "User" object with `Name`, `ProfilePicture`, `Biography`, etc., what would be a good way of achieving that API consistency when adding a new property? Should I update all my microservices so they replicate the newly added property?

Comment: In general, I'd advise having consuming services ignore events that don't affect them ("tolerant reader").  This does argue against publishing a "this User is now" event (or at least against publishing such an event with any properties that you're not sure every consumer can handle) in favor of "this property of this User is now" events (or even better: have the event express _why_ the change happened, e.g. "User updated biography").

Comment: Alright, so, when I'll introduce the `Biography` property to my `User` model in the API (meaning that this property should be present in a user everywhere in the API), i'll set up the consumers first so they can consume events concerning biography changes, and then update the producer, correct?